# openstack instance is not accessible on LAN

Tags: instance, ping, lan, openstack, accessible

i have setup single machine openstack using devstack. my instances running on machine.

```
openstack machine ip 192.168.2.32

instance machine ip 10.0.0.2 and 172.24.4.1
```

i can ping 172.24.4.1 from openstack machine. but i can't ping this machine from personal computer.and can't access instance. How can I solve it?

Ip Forward

```
 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 1
```

/etc/nova/nova.conf

```
flat_interface = em1
flat_network_bridge = br100
vlan_interface = em1
public_interface = br100
network_manager = nova.network.manager.FlatDHCPManager
firewall_driver = nova.virt.libvirt.firewall.IptablesFirewallDriver
compute_driver = libvirt.LibvirtDriver
default_ephemeral_format = ext4...
```

ifconfig

```
br100     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:55:4b:46:0a  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::707a:83ff:fe0f:4db0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:62087 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:71936261 (71.9 MB)  TX bytes:5377931 (5.3 MB)

em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:55:4b:46:0a  
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:55ff:fe4b:460a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:63127 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:39439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:73159657 (73.1 MB)  TX bytes:6162268 (6.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:163787 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:163787 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:495519545 (495.5 MB)  TX bytes:495519545 (495.5 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr de:30:60:02:bc:dc  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:16:3e:11:ee:00  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc16:3eff:fe11:ee00/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:474 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:1581 (1.5 KB)  TX bytes:74117 (74.1 KB)
```

please help. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ping is blocked by default. You should allow ping in security group.

1)1st find out which is security group

Click on instance name -> Security Groups
(It will be `default` if u didn't configure any)

2) Go to Compute -> Access & security
 Select security group -> Manage rules
3) Click Add Rule

Rule - All ICMP
Direction - Ingress

Then Click Add
You will be able to ping to floating IP assigned to instance.